# How to pass callback functions to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, composition

Suppose we have a `Container` component as follows.

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    handleClose = () => {
        // need to ask 'Content' is it okay with closing
        const isContentAgree = /* */;
        if (isContentAgree) this.props.onClose();
    };

    render () {
        const {content: Content} = this.props;
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Close</button>
            <Content {/* some container-specific props */} />
        );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Container content={SomeComponent}/>
```

In this scenario how can I pass a callback function from `SomeComponent` to `Container`? This callback is to be called when the button in the Container is clicked and returns a boolean value.

Comment: See [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep `isContentAgree` in `state` and you can pass function to toggle `isContentAgree` to child component.

```
class Container extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              isContentAgree: false
            }
        }

        toggleContentAgree = (e) => {
            this.setState({ isContentAgree: e.target.value })
        }

        handleClose = () => {
            // need to ask 'Content' is it okay with closing
            const isContentAgree = this.state.isContentAgree;
            if (isContentAgree) this.props.onClose();
        };

        render () {
            const {content: Content} = this.props;
            return (
                <button onClick={this.handleClose}>Close</button>
                <Content toggleContentAgree={this.toggleContentAgree} />
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this.handleClick`? Do you mean `this.handleClose`?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply pass the callback function as prop to the component.

```
<Content onHide={handleClose} />
```

in Component you have to call props.onHide function as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
React.cloneElement(SomeComponent, [props...])
```

And as "props" to pass a function that updates container state.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it using store (Redux/Mobx/ContextAPI). That's the ideal way to do it.

But...

You can still pass the callback function:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    render () {
        const {content: Content, callback} = this.props;
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Close</button>
            <Content onSomething={callback} {/* ... */} />
        );
    }
}

<Container content={SomeComponent} callback={someCallbackFunction}/>
```